# How to apply a jQuery effect to an element before page is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make custom `height` of an element using jQuery. `height` is being changed but an effect (like blink effect) is being shown on page load every time. How to solve this problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.jQuery-Container').height('100px');
});
```

```css
.jQuery-Container {
  background-color: Red;
  height: 700px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jQuery-Container">
  This is text..!!
</div>
```

On page load height of the div is being changed but after the page is fully loaded. I want to change height before the page is fully loaded.

You can See my [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3f7x8v26/).

Comment: You can't. The DOM has to be loaded before JS can execute any instructions to it. this is why you see the FOUC (flash of unstyled content). To avoid this, use CSS to update the UI as this is applied earlier in the page lifecycle

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Is there another way to make effect like this. I can't use css because the effect is depend on condition. So need to use jQuery instead.

Comment: Depends on the condition.  You *can* run JS against elements before the entire DOM is fully loaded, as long as the element you're running it against is fully loaded - but this leads to very messy / non-maintainable code and it's not recommended (and still isn't sure to fix your specific issue).   You don't mention the server-side tech - can you apply a different class based on the condition when the page is rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this, where you run a script immediately after the element, and as long as it is plain javascript, it will work.

```css
.JS-Container {
  background-color: Red;
  height: 700px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script>
    function changeThis(sel) {
      document.querySelector(sel).style.cssText = 'height: 100px;';
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="JS-Container">
    This is a sample text
  </div>
  <script>changeThis('.JS-Container');</script> <!-- this will run before page is fully
                                                 loaded, so no "blink" will occur -->


</body>
```

Comment: But you have made two `divs`. You are making change in the text and I want to change the look of the div (only in one div)

Comment: But how it is making changes in the element at run time?

Comment: @RohitSharma I updated my answer again, showing your exact same sample. What do you mean by _how it is making changes in the element at run time?_

Comment: I have the little knowledge of JS So I was trying to know only How it is working..? But, no problem, now I have understood your answer.

Comment: Sorry to say, but I was trying to apply a jQuery affect on the element before the DOM is ready..! I learnt from your answer that it may be possible using pure javaScript, but I think it may reduce the speed of the page rendering.

Comment: @RohitSharma Just because this technique might slow down page load (if the workload of the script is heavy, which this one isn't), my answer still solve your question, so I can't see a reason why to remove the accept. If the workload increase and become a problem, then you might want to consider doing stuff like this _after_ page load, though that is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

make you div first hidden then after your jquery logic make div visible
CSS

```
.jQuery-Container {
  background-color: Red;
  height: 700px;
  width: 200px;
  display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.jQuery-Container').height('100px').show();
});
```